# JAXBContext compatibility issues

Tags: java, jaxb

I am migrating our team from JAXB 1.x to JAXB 2.1 which is part of JAVA1.6 (rt.jar). 
Everything was going swimingly till it started complaining during run time.

Here is the line of code thats causing the issue.

```
String jaxbPackageName = "com.acme.retail.fuel.ifp";
context = JAXBContext.newInstance(jaxbPackageName, new JAXBClassLoader());
```

I have removed all JAXB 1.x libraries and assets from the project and its build path. Yet the issue persists. Below is the exception message

```
SEVERE: JAXBContext creation failed for context path com.acme.retail.fuel.ifp
Throwable occurred: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1 not found
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:158)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:260)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:383)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:348)
    at com.acme.sureview.fuel.ifsf.application.IFPTranslator.<init>(IFPTranslator.java:167)
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured out my problem. So it appears that the ContextFactory settings needs to be changed as well.
Previous value was:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1
```

I changed it to:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

And that took care of it.

Comment: Or you could delete the `jaxb.properties` file and you will get the default.